# User.Identity.Name An object reference is required for the non-static field

Tags: c#, asp.net

Inside my controller class I have private method which returns logged user which is fetched  using User.Identity.Name as paramater which is all fine.

```
private static Account GetLoggedUser()
{ 
   AccountService accService = new AccountService();
   Account userAccount = accService.GetAccountByUsername(User.Identity.Name);
   return userAccount;
}

public ActionResult Edit()
{
   var userAccount = GetLoggedUser();
...
}
```

Problem is that I'm getting this error on line `User.Identity.Name`

> An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.User.get'

**Error is shown at the compiling time.**

Comment: can you pass in the `User.Identity.Name`? or can you get it using `PrincipalContect` you need to pass in the current user you can get that at the `Page Level` as well if your method requires the user name in `DomainName\\UserName` pass that in use the  `Split("\\")` Method on the name and pass the `string[1]` value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling a non-static object/property from within a static method which they seem in the same class. you need to have an instance of the class before you could use it. or change the method to non-static.

Answer (score 3):

You are retrieving a property of the controller in a static method...

Remove `static` in the `GetLoggedUser()` method

from:

```
private static Account GetLoggedUser()
{
    // your code
}
```

to:

```
private Account GetLoggedUser()
{
    // your code
}
```

Comment: `private Account GetLoggedUser(){ }` in case the OP doesn't understand you.. I've learned to not assume things lol

Comment: +2 not a problem `bas` I was just saying.. I just left a post where people were literally providing the correct answer like you did.. and the OP was like `I don't understand`..that's the only reason I mentioned it.. I have learned quickly on `SO` not to assume..lol your answer is a good one by the way because it actually provides the correct response plus you are showing the OP why it's wrong and where he/she made their initial mistake

Comment: Haha the datetime dude :). Typical isn't it... Thx for the kind words!

Answer (score 2):

You don't have access to your base class instance members in a static method.